# Most efficient way to search a tcl list

Tags: list, tcl

i have a tcl list as below.

```
set mylist [list a b c d e]; # could be more
```

Now i am doing some processing if the list contains the items "c", "d", "e". But i need to skip that processing if and only if the list has either of the below values:

```
set mylist [list a];
```

OR

```
set mylist [list b];
```

OR

```
set mylist [list a b];
```

So if mylist is any of the above three, i skip the processing. But lets say if the list has any values other than the above three combinations, i do the processing.

What is the most efficient way of searching if the list has any of the three combinations.

I have the basic code which is fulfilling my requirement, but i was looking for more efficient way as i am not much familiar with tcl containers.

```
set mylist [list a];

if {[llength $mylist] == 2 && ([lindex $mylist 0] eq "a" || [lindex $mylist 0] eq "b") && ([lindex $mylist 1] eq "a" || [lindex $mylist 1] eq "b")} {
  puts "1. skip the processing"
} elseif {[llength $mylist] == 1 && ([lindex $mylist 0] eq "a" || [lindex $mylist 0] eq "b")} {
  puts "2. skip the processing"
} else { 
  puts "Do the processing" 
}
```

I was wondering if there is any other efficient way to perform the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
if {$mylist in {a b {a b}}} {
    puts "skip the processing"
}
```

A list isn't a string, but we can usually compare lists to strings for equality and order. A list with a single element "a" is comparable to the string "a". If you want to know if a given string is equal to any of the lists in the question, the easiest way is to check if the value of the list is a member of the list `{a b {a b}}`.

***Note:*** This particular solution does not solve all aspects of list equality in general. It works in those cases where it works.

**Efficiency**

Is it really efficient to compare a list to a string when this will cause automatic, repeated reconstruction of the internal representation of the data ("shimmering"). Actually, it is. If one compares the procedures

```
proc foo1 mylist {
    set a 0
    if {$mylist in {a b {a b}}} {set a 92}
    return $a
}

proc foo2 mylist {
    set a 0
    if {$mylist in [list [list a] [list b] [list a b]]} {set a 92}
    return $a
}
```

then `foo1` seems to be faster than `foo2` (different machines may produce different results).

Constructing a list inside the condition evaluation code does not seem to add very much time. This procedure

```
proc foo3 mylist {
    set a 0
    set x [list [list a] [list b] [list a b]]
    if {$mylist in $x} {set a 92}
    return $a
}
```

is somewhere in between `foo1` and `foo2` in speed, but not significantly faster than `foo2`.

One can also do this by invoking `lsearch`:

```
proc foo4 mylist {
    set a 0
    set x [list [list a] [list b] [list a b]]
    if {[lsearch $x $mylist] >= 0} {set a 92}
    return $a
}

proc foo5 mylist {
    set a 0
    set x [list [list a] [list b] [list a b]]
    set i [lsearch $x $mylist]
    if {$i >= 0} {set a 92}
    return $a
}
```

which is comparable to `foo2` and `foo3`.

(In case it needs to be said, `lsearch` is more versatile than the `in` operator, offering e.g. case insensitive lookup, regex lookup, etc. If you need such things, `lsearch` is the best option.)

I've deleted most of my observations and theories on speed after timing the procedures on another machine, which showed quite different results. `foo1` was consistently faster on both machines, though. Since that code is simpler than the other alternatives, I would say this is the way to do it. But to be sure, one needs to time the procedure with one's own machine, whitelist, and code to be performed.

Finally, none of this really matters if I/O occurs inside the procedures, since the I/O will be so much slower than anything else.

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Wouldn't `if {$mylist in [list [list a] [list b] [list a b]] } {....` be better to prevent shimmering?  Or is the `in` operator going to convert everything to a string anyways? [This is .2 microseconds slower, actually]

Comment: @BradLanam: unless my understanding of the source is wrong, the `in` operator indeed forces the operands to strings.

Comment: There are more efficient options possible if you can guarantee that the list you are searching within is sorted. That makes `lsearch -sorted` workable, which uses a binary search. No real point for a list of just three items though.